# WebView growing inifinitely

Tags: android, webview, scrollview

I have a WebView which shows a user-inputted String. However, I want it to be able to load web pages in a iframe.

When I show this: (JavaScript and Plugins have to be enabled to test it)

```
<iframe src="http://santirivera.es" height="100%"/>
```

the WV height starts growing with no end.

My WebView is inside a ScrollView, so scrolling is not an option.

Is there any way for the WV to grow EXACTLY until it reaches the page end, then to stop growing?

Comment: that is strange, did you try add a div with 100% height and place the iframe inside of it again height = 100%.